# Cannot properly Configure Wordpress on Hostinger Servers

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, web, hosting

I am trying to upload my locally developed wordPress website to hostinger and I'm facing this particular issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLNTV.png

Here are the steps I followed to upload my WebSite

1. Created a SQL database on the WebServer and then imported the exported database of the WebSite using phpmyadmin. This process was successful.
2. I was using XAMPP to test my WebSite. So I went to xampp/htocs and made a zip file of the wordPress folder. And uploaded it using hostinger's 'Import Website' Feature.
3. After importing the website it automatically extracted the .zip file to public_html folder.
4. I modified the wp-config.php file inside my wordPress folder on the server, changing the database_name, username and password.
5. Then I accessed the site from my domain, I got 'MyBlog' folder there and now when I click on it, I get this error message. Link attached above.

So where did I go wrong in this process? Am I missing some of the steps? Please Help! I just tried the same procedure on two different hosting services and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Search & replace Database Script [Here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), upload on your server and replace all localhost links with your website URLs. Let say localhost/newwebsite to example.com. It will replace all URLs by using Serialization technique...Once all database URls replaced, your website will become functional.